# Can't update Uber app

Tags: updates, application-autoupdate, uber

I installed uber app from play store. But when i try to update it then it cant update and it shows error.[image]

Comment: Are you able to update other apps? Tried removing and reinstalling the uber app?

Comment: Yes. I can update other apps. But uber can't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below Step:

1. Go to Setting
2. Tap on Applications
3. Find the Uber app on a downloaded app
4. Tap on Uber app
5. Clear caches files and clear data storage.
6. Now open Play Store
7. Find Uber app, let see UPDATE button is visible